# Using JQuery slideToggle with dynamicall generated PHP information

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

I have thoroughly confused myself.

I have a page with information that is dynamically generated with PHP. I am trying to use jQuery to hide and reveal the information. However, when I execute the code the function only works on the first instance.

Here's the html/php code:

```
<div id="container">

<?php

foreach ($datas as $name)
{
    if ($name['state'] === 'PA') 
    {
        echo
        '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $name['id'] . '" />' .
        '<h1 id="name">' . htmlentities($name['name']) . '</h1>' .
        '<p id="descriptionlist">' .
        htmlentities($name['description']) . ' ' .
        '<br />' .
        '<ul id="link">' .
        '<li class="l1">' .
        '<a href="' . $name['site'] . '"target="_blank">' . $name['sname'] . '</a>' .
        '</li>' .
        '</ul>' .                           
        '</p>' .

'<div id = "locBar' . $name['id'] . '">' .  '<div id="locText' . $name['id'] . '">' .   
'<h2 id="location">Location</h2>' .
'</div>' . '</div>' .
'<div id="locDiv' . $name['id'] . '">' .
```

Here's the jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#locBar').click(function(){
$('#locDiv').slideToggle('slow')
})
});
```

Obviously, jQuery doesn't understand that if I am clicking the div in the second iteration, that anything should happen.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The jQuery probably needs to be changed to reflect something like `$('#locDiv*NAME_ID_HERE*')` since the PHP code creates IDs based on the `$name['id']` variable.

Comment: drew: I thought of that, but couldn't figure out how to do it.  Undefined: although that's true, it doesn't really tell me how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does the generated html look like?
Im guessing as this is the beginning of a foreach loop, you are generating multiple divs with the same ID (locBar and locDiv). You should never have multiple items with the same ID.
Change it to use class instead